# JAva:How to pass a custom object type as a parameter to a method and return the same custom object type value back

Tags: java

I am using JDBC template to get my query results from database. I had written the below working code to get my query results converted into the custom object "test" (for which I have a written class for separately).

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<test>(test.class) );
```

My question is can the above code be made generic/reusable as a method so as to allow any kind of object to be passed as a parameter to this method and return type as the same object as well? Something like the non working code shown as below?

```
public static calledClass ExecuteQuery(String sql,Class calledClass) {       
   return  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sqlCommand,new BeanPropertyRowMapper<calledClass>(calledClass.class))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `JdbcTemplate`, `queryForObject()` is declared as :

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException
```

So, something like that should do the job :

```
public static <T> T executeQuery(String sql,Class<T> calledClass){      
      return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<T>(calledClass));
}
```